# Create an activity that doesn't take up the entire screen

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to create an activity in Android that doesn't take up the entire screen? I would like to create one that is only 1 pixel x 1 pixel wide and launch it.

Comment: make full screen transparent with no title bar no action bar :)

Comment: You can use Dialog Theme in Manifest,then your activity will appear as dialog and not on full screen

Comment: But can you make the dialog only 1px x 1px in size?

Comment: If you make the screen transparent, is it still going to react to tapping or will the taps go to whatever is below this transparent activity?

Comment: Are you planning for mal function application? If you don't have nothing to do with activity, try using creating service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not. An Activity is designed to be the current active screen. 
You can 'fool' people with the view that goes with the Activity, such as making it (partly) transparent but your Activity will still be the one receiving touches.

Answer (score 0):

Create activity with dialog Theme by using this

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: What exactly does that do?

Comment: That will create your activity as dialog, which will appear on screen as dialog. This will not blink screen as user get to know that some other application is launched.

Comment: It is possible to create a dialog only 1px x 1px in size?

Answer (score 0):

Activities are often presented to the user as full-screen windows,

They can also be used in other ways: as floating windows (via a theme with windowIsFloating set)
 or
 embedded inside of another activity (using ActivityGroup).

If you want to create with given pixel you can not do it.. Instead you can go for Fragments, DialogInterface in Android which can be created with size specified in layout xmls